# How can i create a <hr> line with a few big dots

Tags: html, css

I coded this line

```html
<hr style="border-style: dotted; size: 5px; background-color: #EAF6F6;">
```

How can i create a line like that? :

[image]

Comment: 1. Use image; 2. use 5 elements with `border-radius: 50%; height: 5px; width: 5px;`

Comment: how can i use 5 elements? i dont really understand how to create 5 dots next to each other like in the picture. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how you can do it. You have to use borders. It is a very handy trick that comes into use a lot. You can not only create dotted lines but all sorts of other ones as well by defining the border for hr tag.

```css
hr {
    width: 20%;
    border-style: dotted none none;
    border-width: 7px;
    border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use gradient coloration:

```css
.dots {
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
  margin:auto;
  background:radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#EAF6F6 98%,#0000) 0/calc(100%/5) 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots"></div>
```

You can introduce a CSS variable to easily control the number of dots:

```css
.dots {
  --n:5;
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
  margin:20px auto;
  background:radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#EAF6F6 98%,#0000) 0/calc(100%/var(--n)) 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots"></div>
<div class="dots" style="--n:3"></div>
<div class="dots" style="--n:7"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use border-top or border-bottom as following.

```
<hr style="background-color: inherit;border-bottom: 5px dotted #d2d2d2;">
```